# FortiClient VPN 6.4 blocks internet access on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, vpn

Every time I'm in an active connection on FortiClient VPN, I lose my internet access. I tried on Windows and it just works fine and it was a SSL connection.

I also tried using the 6.0 version, but could not get to the application to start. Has anyone ever had this issue with running FortiClient VPN on Ubuntu 20.04?

Answer (score 0):

On my 20.04 LTS, Forticlient VPN v6.4.0.0851 never got connected, it would say connecting.

openfortivpn(available in package manager) and [openfortigui](https://hadler.me/linux/openfortigui/) works for me.

openfortivpn - v1.12.0-1, openfortigui - v0.9.3

edit: have tested after complete removal of official forticlient.